# avoid jquery confllict

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery to scale image, it works fine on test [html](http://techchef.co/devTest/test/)

But it show error, look like conflict error when i try to implement it in the live website as other js also call on it, it shows the below error

> `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`*  on line 1 in `base.js`

i tried below code for avoid conflict but it not works look like i am missing some thing

```
jquery.noconflict();
$(document).ready(on_ready);
function on_ready() {
$('#search').defaultVal('search here...');
$('#comment').defaultVal('your comment here...');
$('#message').defaultVal('your message here...');
.....
```

`base.js` file can be seen on the below mentioned link

http://techchef.co/devTest/test/base.js

Comment: try 'jQuery' instead of '$'. You can use '$' if you don't call jQuery.noconflict()

Comment: just read this page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// cannot use '$' because of .noConflict()
// now the '$'-sign is free for other libraries e.b. MooTools...
// ...that's what noConflict does

// try using 'jQuery' instead of '$' here
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.selector').click(function() {
        // and so on
    });
});

// or an other solution looks like this

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
    });
})(jQuery)

// in your case try

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // the code you have in your on_ready-function
});

// or

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    on_ready();
});
function on_ready() {
    // your on_ready-function
}
```

[MORE INFO](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict)

Comment: when i am trying to do this like below it shows error, & doesn't detect the function call on the page where i am calling its call

`jQuery.noConflict()

jQuery(document).ready(function(on_ready){

function on_ready() {
    $('#search').defaultVal('search here...');
    $('#comment').defaultVal('your comment here...');
    $('#message').defaultVal('your message here...');
});
`

Comment: actually by default base.js calls the **on_ready** function like below

`$(document).ready(on_ready);
function on_ready() {
    $('#search').defaultVal('search here...');
    $('#comment').defaultVal('your comment here...');
    $('#message').defaultVal('your message here...');
`

Comment: kindly guide me what to do in this case

Comment: actually simply i just want to increase transform scale value of css of the element

Answer (score 0):

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
j("div p").hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';
```

[see this documentation for more information.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 0):

when i am trying to do this like below it shows error, & doesn't detect the function call on the page where i am calling its call

```
jQuery.noConflict() 
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{ 
function on_ready() { $('#search').defaultVal('search here...');     
$('#comment').defaultVal('your comment here...'); 
$('#message').defaultVal('your message here...'); });
```

})

actually by default base.js calls the on_ready function like below

```
$(document).ready(on_ready); 
function on_ready() {
 $('#search').defaultVal('search here...');
 $('#comment').defaultVal('your comment here...');
 $('#message').defaultVal('your message here...');
```

Comment: Hey the method 'defaultVal' is not a jQuery-function. When you select a DOM-Element with jQuery or '$', the object is extended with jQuery-function. As usual it is an array where you can use the jQuery-function. 'defaultVal' is no such function and afaik 'defaultVal' is no default javascript-function. If you want to change the value-attribute of an jQuery-element, use .val('value') as function. If you want to change the text between two html-tag use .text(). See here http://api.jquery.com/text/ and http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 0):

I just  resolved this issue by replacing `$` with `jQuery` in `base.js`

It worked for me. Hope it helps.